# Windows form c#, encryption and adding additional character

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption

How do I encrypt passwords in such a way that it not only changes the characters of the password but also add extra characters. For example a password as "ABC" would become "12345" instead of "123". Another way is that for each character, the key shift is different. Below are my codes.

```
class CipherMachine
    {
        static private List<char> Charset =
            new List<char>("PQOWIEURYTLAKSJDHFGMZNXBCV"
                + "olpikmujnyhbtgvrfcedxwszaq"
                + "1597362480"
                + "~!@#$%^&*()_+"
                + "PQOWIEURYTLAKSJDHFGMZNXBCV"
                + "olpikmujnyhbtgvrfcedxwszaq"
                + "1597362480"
                + "~!@#$%^&*()_+");
        static private int Key = 39;
        //static private int Length = 0;
        static public string Encrypt(string plain)
        {
            string cipher = "";
            foreach (char i in plain)
            {
                cipher += Charset.ElementAt(Charset.IndexOf(i) + Key);
                //cipher += Charset.ElementAt(Charset.IndexOf(i) + Length);
            }
            return cipher;
        }
        static public string Decrypt(string cipher)
        {
            string plain = "";
            foreach (char i in cipher)
            {
                plain += Charset.ElementAt(Charset.LastIndexOf(i) - Key);
                //plain += Charset.ElementAt(Charset.LastIndexOf(i) - Length);
            }
            return plain;
        }
    }
}
```

Lines that are commented out are what I thought I could do but it turned out wrong.

Comment: If this is for anything other than a little programming exercise **don't encode passwords like this**. It's a very weak and easily breakable scheme. If you're storing password, always make sure to salt and hash them using a secure hash algorithm.

Comment: Yes, this is actually an assignment for school. So it's somewhat an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You have made the string double length so that the `+ Key` and `- Key` works, but you ought to have one string of all characters and then WRAP the index (so that if the index goes beyond the length of the string, it wraps back to the beginning). You can achieve this with the % modulus operator:

```
static private List<char> Charset =
        new List<char>("PQOWIEURYTLAKSJDHFGMZNXBCV"
            + "olpikmujnyhbtgvrfcedxwszaq"
            + "1597362480"
            + "~!@#$%^&*()_+");
int length = Charset.Count();

// to encrypt
int key = 24;
char unencryptedChar = 'P';
int unencryptedIndex = Charset.IndexOf(unencryptedChar);
int encryptedIndex = (unencryptedIndex + key) % length;
char encryptedChar = Charset.ElementAt(encryptedIndex);

// to unencrypt
int encryptedIndex = Charset.IndexOf(encryptedChar);
int unencryptedIndex = (encryptedIndex - key + length) % length;
char unencryptedChar = Charset.ElementAt(unencryptedIndex);
```

When you subtract the `key` in the second part, the index goes negative, and modulus won't work properly on a negative, so we add the `length` (though this only works if the `key` is smaller than the `length`).

Comment: You are using very primitive symmetric-key [cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography). It's weak. If e.g you change 1 char in input stream you get 1 char changed in output stream which makes obtaining key a very easy job. Alphabet-based encryption can be easily predicted by using statistic (hacker can see word "delimiters" and can find out other characters by guessing and checking). Consider to use more advanced [techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/q/202011/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr, who is "You"? Is this meant to be a comment for his question or my answer?

Comment: Yes, it suppose to be a comment to question, sorry =D

Comment: int length = Charset.Length(); gives an error which is it does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method.

Comment: It should be `Charset.Count()`. I have changed it.

Comment: int key = 24;
char unencryptedChar = 'P';
int unencryptedIndex = Charset.IndexOf(unencryptedChar);
int encryptedIndex = (unencryptedIndex + key) % length;
char encryptedChar = Charset.ElementAt(encryptedIndex);   Are these codes supposed to be added in into my current codes or ?

Comment: @MbrGpt No, they are examples only.